# Demystify CSS minify and merging work flow from existing ZF1 project

Tags: css, zend-framework, merge, zend-studio

I have an existing ZF1 project. I can't figure out how the css files were managed previously. Hope some ZF1 expert can help me.

The public site front will load the css from /css/normal.css, but this file looks like exported or generated. Because under the css folder, there is

```
css/
  normal.css <-- css content, web front loads
  front/
    front.css
    items.css
    layout.css
    normal.css <-----this file only imports the other 3 .css files
```

`@import 'front.css';@import 'layout.css';@import 'items.css';`

All these .css files are minified. There are .gz file beside the .css file so the real files are

```
css/
  normal.css
  normal.css.gz
  front/
    front.css
    front.css.gz
    layout.css
    layout.css.gz
    items.css
    items.css.gz
    normal.css
    normal.css.gz
```

This is on production server. To me, all the `minify`, `merging` probably happens before uploading to the server. I wonder if Zend Studio did that.
(If it does, it's pretty cool.) or any other tool.

So I want to know what's the work flow if any one can tell?
Or at least how to generate the merged normal.css file under /css from the "import" .css. It does make sense given the "import" is not behaving quite well in loading comparing to loading css file directly.

I can't figure out the point of .gz file here. It might be part of the process of the tool.

Comment: ZF has nothing built in to do this. I've never used Zend Studio, so can't comment there, but it's possible. If not then the answer is likely to be specific to your project. The .gz files are likely just gzipped versions of the main CSS files.

Comment: https://github.com/hobodave/bundle-phu I found this which is similar.